# How can I handle the data of post requests in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to receive a request by adding several inputs to the form by the user.
I want to know how to control the received data separately.
in html file, {% for i in request.POST.items %} it works. but in views.py, it doesn't work like this

views.py

```
def debate_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        content = request.POST

        for k,v in content.items:
            if k == 'sup_title':
                sup_title = SuperTitle()
                sup_title.author = request.user
                sup_title.super_title = v
                sup_title.save()
            elif 'img' not in k and 'section' in k:
                sub_title = Subtitle()
                sub_title.super_title = sup_title.super_title.id
                sub_title.sub_title = v
                sub_title.save()
            elif 'img' in k:
                stg = Images()
                imgs = request.FILES
                stg.images = imgs
                stg.sub_title = sub_title.sub_title.id
                stg.save()
            elif 'section' in k and 'opt' in k:
                opt = SelectOption()
                opt.sub_title = sub_title.sub_title.id
                opt.option = v
        return render(request, 'polls/test.html')
```

models.py

```
class SuperTitle(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='debate_author')
    super_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    liker = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='debate_liker')

class Subtitle(models.Model):
    super_title = models.ForeignKey(SuperTitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_title = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Images(models.Model):
    sub_title = models.ForeignKey(Subtitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(null=True)


class SelectOption(models.Model):
    sub_title = models.ForeignKey(Subtitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    option_voter = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

html

```
    <form method="POST" id="debate_form" action="{% url 'polls:debate_create' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='text' name='sup_title' placeholder='제목'>
        <div id="form_container">
            <section id='section_1'>
                <input type="text" name="section_1">
                <input type="file" name="img_section_1" multiple>
                <div id="section_1_div">
                    <input type="text" name="section_1_opt_1" value="1">
                    <input type="text" name="section_1_opt_2" value="2">
                </div>
                <input type="button" value="add option" onclick='add_option(this.id)' id="section_1">
                <input type="button" value="sub option" onclick='sub_option(this.id)' id="section_1">
            </section>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value='add content' onclick='add_content()'>
        <input type="button" value='sub content' onclick='sub_content()'>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

There was a confusion between the django syntax in HTML and the syntax in python.

html

```
{% for i in request.POST.items %}
```

views.py

```
#for i in request.POST.items >>> syntaxerror 
for i in request.POST.items():
```